# Remote Administrative Access to a server, KVM over IP or HP iLo?

Tags: server, remote-server, kvm

We have a situation. We want to grant remote administrative access to one of our servers for clients. As I know, there are two possible ways: 1- `KVM-over-IP` and 2-HP `iLO`. The most important thing for us is security. Next we would like to consider other issues like performance and management access levels which we can offer to our clients. Can any one give me a brief comparison between these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

KVM over IP is simply access to physical computer console (screen, keyboard, mouse, USB etc.).

iLO is a kind of remote control interface, using which administrator can control the server below the operating system layer, and even below the physical console, BIOS/UEFI etc.

If you give iLO access to someone, that person will have the complete control over the server. If your customer needs to eg. install his own operating system, it would be completely enough to give him KVM access.